# A cart that uses SessionID

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to create a cart that I can easily add some item or simply help someone at the other end over the phone.  I decided to create a cart that would store everything on MySQL instead of using `$_SESSION`.

I did not code the whole cart just in case that this idea is very very bad. But I wanted to show what I have done and know your feedback.

The MySQL table look like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checkouts` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SessionId` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `LastTouchTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ObjectSerialized` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

And this is the PHP class:

```
class Checkout
{
    static $KeepCartFor = 86400;
    static $dbCon = null;
    private $CheckoutId = null;
    private $Cart = array();
    private $PromoCode = null;
    private $SubTotal = 0.00;
            // Please Note that im using GST as the rst ( the cart is kinda made for   easy swap between canada store and usa
    private $Gst = 0.00; //Good And Services Taxes
    private $Pst = 0.00; //Provincial Tax
    private $Shipping = array("Method"=>null,"Cost"=>0.00);
    private $Total = 0.00;

    private $Customer = array("FirstName"=>null,"LastName"=>null,"Email"=>null,"Home"=>null,"Work"=>null,"Cell"=>null,"Fax"=>null,"Company"=>null,"Address1"=>null,"Address2"=>null,"Address3"=>null,"Country"=>null,"State"=>null,"City"=>null,"Zip"=>null,"isShippingSameAsBilling"=>true,"ShipFirstName"=>null,"ShipLastName"=>null,"ShipCompany"=>null,"ShipAddress1"=>null,"ShipAddress2"=>null,"ShipAddress3"=>null,"ShipCountry"=>null,"ShipState"=>null,"ShipCity"=>null,"ShipZip"=>null);

    public function Cart_AddItem($WebsiteId,$Qty = 1)
    {
        if(!isset($this->Cart[$WebsiteId]))
        {
            $this->Cart[$WebsiteId] = $this->_GetProductDetail($WebsiteId);
            $this->Cart[$WebsiteId]['Qty'] = $Qty;
        }
        else
            $this->Cart[$WebsiteId]['Qty'] += $Qty;
        $this->Shipping = array("Method"=>null,"Cost"=>0.00);
    }
    public function Cart_RemoveItem($WebsiteId,$Qty = null)
    {
        if(isset($this->Cart[$WebsiteId]))
            if(is_null($Qty))
                unset($this->Cart[$WebsiteId]);
            else
            {
                if($this->Cart[$WebsiteId]['Qty'] - $Qty <= 0)
                    unset($this->Cart[$WebsiteId]);
                else
                    $this -> Cart[$WebsiteId]['Qty'] -= $Qty;
            }
        $this->Shipping = array("Method"=>null,"Cost"=>0.00);
    }
    public function Cart_Emtpy()
    {
        $this -> Cart = array();
        $this -> SubTotal = 0.0;
        $this -> Gst = 0.00;
        $this -> Pst = 0.00;
        $this -> Total = 0.00;
    }
    public function Cart_GetItems($WithDetail = false)
    {
        if(!$WithDetail)
        {
            foreach($this->Cart as $WebsiteId => $Vars)
            {
                $Return[$WebsiteId] = $Vars['Qty'];
            }
            return $Return;
        }
        else
            return $this->Cart;
    }
    private function _RefrechCartVars()
    {
        $this->SubTotal = 0.00;
        $this->Gst = 0.00;
        $this->Pst = 0.00;
        $this->Total = 0.00;
        foreach($this->Cart as $WebsiteId => $Vars)
        {
            $this->SubTotal += $Vars['ActualPrice']*$Vars['Qty'];
        }
        if(($this->Customer['isShippingSameAsBilling']?$this->Customer['Country']:$this->Customer['ShipCountry']) == "United States")
            if(($this->Customer['isShippingSameAsBilling']?$this->Customer['State']:$this->Customer['ShipState']) == "New York")
                $this->Gst = ($this->SubTotal * 0.07) + (is_null($this->Shipping['Method'])?0.00:$this->Shipping['Cost']);
        $this->Total = $this->SubTotal + $this->Gst + (is_null($this->Shipping['Method'])?0.00:$this->Shipping['Cost']);
    }
    private function _GetProductDetail($WebsiteId)
    {
        $GetProductDetail = Checkout::$dbCon -> prepare("SELECT * FROM product WHERE id = :Id");
        $GetProductDetail -> bindValue(':Id',$WebsiteId);
        try{
            $GetProductDetail->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e)
        {die("Error Getting Product Detail :".$e->getMessage());}
        $PD = $GetProductDetail->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $Return['Brand'] = $PD['brand'];
        $Return['ModelNumber'] = $PD['SKU'];
        $Return['Title'] = $PD['title'];
        $Return['ActualPrice'] = ($PD['pricingtype'] =='promo' && strtotime($PD['enddate']) >= time()?$PD['promoprice']:$PD['price']);
        $Return['MSRP'] = $PD['originalprice'];
        $Return['PictureUrl'] = $PD['picturelink'];
        $Return['Weight'] = $PD['weight'];
        $Return['DimensionalWeight'] = number_format($PD['height']*$PD['length']*$PD['width']/166,2);
        $Return['CalculatedWeight'] = ($Return['Weight']>=$Return['DimensionalWeight']?$Return['Weight']:$Return['DimensionalWeight']);
        return $Return;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
//         Check if have an checkout already
        $Prepare = Checkout::$dbCon ->prepare("SELECT * FROM checkouts WHERE SessionId = :SessionId AND LastTouchTime >= :Time ORDER BY Id DESC");
        $Prepare -> bindValue(':SessionId',session_id());
        $Prepare -> bindValue(':Time',time()-self::$KeepCartFor);
        try{
            $Prepare -> execute();
            if($Prepare -> rowCount() != 0)
            {
                $Checkout = $Prepare->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                $this->CheckoutId = $Checkout['Id'];
                $ThisVar = unserialize($Checkout['ObjectSerialized']);
                foreach($ThisVar as $Key => $Val)
                    $this->$Key = $Val;
                $this->CheckoutId = $Checkout['Id'];
            }
        }catch(PDOException $e)
        { die("Error Getting Checkout From Db: ".$e->getMessage()); }
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        if(is_null($this->CheckoutId))
        {// Insert Checkout In Mysql
            $CheckWhatIsNextId = Checkout::$dbCon->prepare("SELECT Id FROM checkouts ORDER BY Id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
            $CheckWhatIsNextId -> execute();
            $NextId = $CheckWhatIsNextId -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this->CheckoutId = $NextId['Id'];

            $InsertCheckout = Checkout::$dbCon->prepare("INSERT INTO checkouts (`SessionId`,`LastTouchTime`,`ObjectSerialized`) VALUES(:SessionId,:LastTouchTime,:ObjectSer);");
            $InsertCheckout -> bindValue(':SessionId',session_id());
            $InsertCheckout -> bindValue(':LastTouchTime',time());
            $InsertCheckout -> bindValue(':ObjectSer',serialize($this));
            try{
                $InsertCheckout -> execute();
            }catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die("Error SavingCart In Db: ".$e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $UpdateCheckout = Checkout::$dbCon->prepare("UPDATE `checkouts` SET `LastTouchTime` = :Time,ObjectSerialized = :Object WHERE `Id` = :Id;");
            $UpdateCheckout -> bindValue(':Time',time());
            $UpdateCheckout -> bindValue(':Object',serialize($this));
            $UpdateCheckout -> bindValue(':Id',$this->CheckoutId);
            try{
                $UpdateCheckout -> execute();
            }catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                die("Error SavingCart In Db: ".$e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this next class is simply a little class for my laziness of remembering the DSN of MySQL and port and all for PDO objects:

```
class dbCon extends PDO
{
    public function __construct($host,$port,$user,$pass,$dbName=null)
    {
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host.';port='.$port.';';
        if(!is_null($dbName))
            $dsn .='dbname='.$dbName;
        try{
            parent::__construct($dsn,$user,$pass,$pdo_options);
        }catch(PDOException $e){ die("Error Connecting To Database: ".$e->getMessage() ); }

    }
}
```

Technically on any page I can access the cart with only 2 line of code:

```
Checkout::$dbCon = new dbCon("127.0.0.1",3306,"UserName","Password","DatabaseName");
$Checkout = new Checkout();
```

Maybe there is some security issue that I'm not thinking about, or perhaps I should do something different.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Database

- Normalize your database! Don't keep a string of serialized objects in the database, that's extremely brittle and extremely not helpful in all but the most simple cases. Instead, you should have 3 tables (two of which you already have):

  - `items` - Table that holds information about items, includes name, price, etc.
    Key column: `item_id`.
  - `carts` (renamed from checkout) - Table that holds information about user's carts. There's a 1:1 relationship between carts and checkouts, a single cart can't be checked out more than once, and a single checkout doesn't apply to multiple carts. So it makes sense to have them in the same table. Has the cart's ID, the user's ID (in your case, `SessionID`) and extra information (not items) like `LastTouchTime`.
    Key column: `cart_id`
  - `items-in-carts`. Items and carts have a **many to many relationship**, also known as n:m ratio. One cart can have multiple items in it, and the same item can be in multiple carts. So we have a third table that ties the two together. All the table has is two columns: `item_id`, `cart_id`. **[Here's an example for a many-to-many architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923809/many-to-many-relationships-examples)**.

### PHP

- Naming convention - `ClassNames` should be CamelCaps, `$variableNames` and `methodNames()` should be lowercase camelCase. Don't mix caps with underscores (for example, `Cart_AddItem` should be just `addItem`, it clear we're talking about the cart here, isn't it?)
- Use of static variables and methods - Don't. Static variables and methods are **global**, which means that by definition they make your application less stable, harder to test and maintain, and harder to read. Please don't.
- `__construct()` function should always be first - The first thing I read about a class is how it's constructed.
- Implicit dependencies - Your `__construct()` says it doesn't need any parameters, but that's a lie. It actually needs a database connection, and you're using a global to get it. That's what I mean by "don't use static variables". This is a better approach:

  ```
  public function __construct(DBCon $dbCon) {
  ```
- Consistent spacing - Sometimes you use `$var->method()` and sometimes `$var -> method()` make up your mind, and stick with it. There are free tools that can do this job for you!
- Naming of things - Why is it called a Checkout? What I see is a Cart, and that's how it should be called. If you can checkout a cart, you should have a method `$cart->checkout(...)`. Your methods are redundantly long, `Cart_Empty()` can be `empty()`, `Cart_AddItem()` can be `addItem()`.
- Too much going on in once class - Your cart uses Items right? Why not make an `Item` class?
- What's the purpose of the `dbCon` object? - Why are you placing another abstraction on top of PDO? What problem are you solving here? On 99% of the application (and I bet including yours), you only ever need a single database connection, so what's the point of wrapping it in a class that hinders readability (I know the PDO, but I see `dbCon` and I have no idea what it is, until I dive in and read the code).

All-in-all, I'd try to adopt a more OOP approach, create more class, increase the interaction between objects. **Get rid of the globals and statics**.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment/subjection.   Id like to to say that the main purpuse of all this actualy was to make a full checkout system,. ( that is why I had Cart_addItem and so on. ) Also, The only reason why $dbCon is static is that when you serialize an object if there is an object that is a resource or PDO Object it can't be serialize, But I just got an idea while actuly writing this comment il try to use `__sleep`   Again thanks alots for your time and your subjection.

Comment: Please don't serialize objects and save into the database. The results are unpredictable at best, and app-breaking at worse. Please, for your sake, don't.

Comment: I might sound ignorant but, Why? I have been using serialize for quite some time now and I never encounter something that is unpredictable, I am very willing to change the code to some normalized string, But only if I see some benefice. How can it be unpredictable? Do you have some fact that back what you are saying?

Comment: Well, here are some: You lose indexability (that hurts!), If you make changes to your table's interface or variable names, it invalidates all of your already stored serials. Performing a search by a specific thing in an object is impossible. You tightly couple the database with PHP (You cannot migrate to Java or a different server technology later). Is that enough reasoning, or would you like me to continue?

Comment: Lol, You win. Actually indexability is probably a big part,. You are right. You see I was not even considering the fact that I will need to find and edit a cart after the cart have been made,..          Any how Thanks for you input Madara!

Comment: Sure thing ;) This is what this site is for. I actually put [so] on hold in favor of here to help people who actually want to help themselves.